# Azure Logic app for newsletter downloading

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

Hello I am currently stuck with problem with logic app.

Task: I need to access email and if there a newsletter then i need to download it into the data lake as a pdf file so that i can use this pdf for further tasks.

Newsletter which is received looks as the below link:

[image: Example newsletter attachment,(https://github.com/InterNations/antwort)]

Currently, I can open the email. But i am not sure whether to save those newsletter links and create separate logic app/functions app to open link and save it as PDF.

[image: Logic App flow]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, we could able to achieve your requirement using 3rd party connector action called `Convert HTML to PDF` of `plumsail` connector. You just need to log in to plumsail and create an API (which doesn't cost anything) in order to create the connection. Then save the resultant pdf to your blob.

Considering the same sample as yours here is the mail that we will be receiving.

[image]

**Here is my logic app flow:-**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**In my storage account**

[image]

**In my local machine after downloading**

[image]